# Why did I lose reputation

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

I recently commented on an [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/443975/ms-sql-server-db-version-without-restoring/444081#444081) that I considered to be unhelpful and of low quality, to then find when the answer was down voted my account also lost rep.

Why is this?

Surely the helpful comment should not attract a reduction in reputation.

My Reputation earlier today was 233 and is now 232

Comment: It's just one point man, don't sweat it. =)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/privileges/vote-down - mods don't get to see if you downvote ;)

Comment: its not the amount of rep I have a problem with, i just don't think its the correct way to "reward" someone for a good comment.

Comment: @MikeT: It's nothing to do with the comment. I suspect you downvoted the answer and as the link above explains when you do that, you loose one rep point and the OP looses two.

Comment: That sounds plausible to me, I just didn't realise that it may have been for the down vote, its not something I normally do.

Comment: @Iain Nope, I'm the single downvote on that "answer," not MikeT.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: the answer has 2 downvotes - so now they're accounted for.

Comment: @Iain  Dear God, you're right.  So the important question becomes who upvoted that... thing?

Comment: @HopelessN00b We've got serial upvoters going for the Electorate badge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much rep did you lose ? Looking at your account there is no indication that you have lost any rep at all.

Comment: +1 Your account shows that you have never lost any reputation.... Also, comments can't lead to a loss of reputation.

Comment: The answer has now been removed and my rep on serverfault has been restored to its original value (but not on here yet)

Comment: Looks like you downvoted the Answer. You got a +1 "refund" when I delete the crap answer. However, I still don't see where you ever lost the point in the first place... Meta does take a little while to cache your new rep, that's normal.

Comment: @ChrisS: Remember voting is private and even mods don't get to see how someone voted so we wouldn't see a -1 for a downvote.

Comment: @Iain Nevermind; I'm dumb. We can see things he earned reputation for. He got 232 points in "up" reputation, which is where he was... I was thinking "no -1 in there"... I forgot you start at 1, so 1 + 232 => 233 and he was at 232.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget you can go to https://serverfault.com/reputation and see every reputation-affecting event for your account ever.

My guess is that a recalc happened and there was a discrepancy by 1 which has now been corrected.